# DJI Phantom 3 standard Connectivity issue

Tags: android, ios, wif, connectivity, dji-sdk

Based on my reading, in Phantom 3 standard, the craft, controller and the mobile app all connected to the WIFI access point of the wifi on the controller.

Can we still send data back through mobile internet to a server from on the mobile app using DJI SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately its a limitation in many Android phones that they do not connect to Wifi and mobile internet at the same time. FYI. In iPhone this works fine.